# A torsion free sheaf of rank $1$ on a nodal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a irreducible curve which has a unique node, $\pi \colon X^{\prime}\rightarrow X$ be the normalization, and $\mathcal{F}$ be a torsion free sheaf of rank $1$ on $X$.
Then,$\pi^{*}\mathcal{F}/\mbox{torsion}$ is a line bundle on $X^{\prime}$.

I want to show the following lemma,

> The natural map $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \pi_{*}(\pi^{*}\mathcal{F}/\mbox{torsion})$ is injective and has a torsion cokernel.

$\pi$ is an isomorphism outside the node of $X$. Let $x\in X$ be the node, and I want to show $\mathcal{F}_{x}\rightarrow (\pi_{*}(\pi^{*}\mathcal{F}/\mbox{torsion}))_{x}$ is injective, but I don't know how the pushforward $\pi_{*}$ works on the stalk.

I think this may be a dumb question, but I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stalk of the pushforward at the node will just be isomorphic to the direct sum of the stalks along $\pi^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks. Put $\pi^{-1}(x)=\{y,z\}$, then $(\pi^{*}\mathcal{F}/\mbox{torsion}))_{x}\cong \mathcal{O}_{y}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{z}$ ? and Why $\mathcal{O}_{x} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{y}\oplus \mathcal{O}_{z}$ is injective?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is torsion free, it is pure of dimension 1, i.e. the support of every nonzero coherent subsheaf of $\mathcal{F}$ has dimension 1 (if you are not familiar with this property, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149374/characterization-of-torsion-free-sheaves)). The kernel of the map $\mathcal{F}\to\pi_*(\pi^*\mathcal{F}/\mathrm{torsion})$, if nonzero, is supported at $x$.
Thus the kernel has to be zero.